# Rotating return value by ratio function the pythonista way

Tags: python

I have a **function return value rotate by ratio** as setup, currently I use a thing like priority queue to make this work but what is these a **good performance** and **pythonista** way to do this.

This is example of how I need my function work

I have setup:

```
value  | ratio
A        2
B        1
C        3
```

and a function use that setup:

```
setup = {'A': 2, 'B': 1, 'C': 3} #create from setup above
def process():
    ...
    value = ...
    return value
```

result whever I call the function:

```
process()
>>> A
process()
>>> A
process()
>>> B
process()
>>> C
process()
>>> C
process()
>>> C
process()
>>> A
process()
>>> A
process()
>>> B
process()
>>> C
... #and so on
```

Comment: The pythonista way is the one that works and other people can understand.

Comment: How do one guarantee that you can recover the original order of the keys in setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite my slightly snarky comment, iterators are indeed the way to go here:

```
from itertools import cycle, chain, repeat
def process(setup):
    # to use a dictionary, just change the end to in setup.items()
    return cycle(chain.from_iterable(repeat(c, n) for c, n in setup))

# A namedtuple would also be appropriate here
setup = [('A', 2), ('B', 1), ('C', 3)]

it = process(setup) # global variables are of the devil
print next(it) # repeat ad nauseam
```

The way that one-liner works is:

1. The generator expression with `repeat(c, n)` gives you iterators yielding the sequences `['A', 'A']`, `['B']` and `['C', 'C', 'C']`
2. `chain.from_iterable()` joins them into `['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']`
3. `cycle()` makes that last sequence repeat endlessly
4. Successive calls to `next()` will return values from that endless sequence.

Comment: although this need import `itertools` from python lib but I prefer this over the function in function way `_iterator_to_rotating_function(_build_cycle(SETUP))` or `while True and yield` way.

Comment: @Hardy This is, however, exactly the same as the `while True` and `yield` way, except those constructs are encapsulated by the `itertools` functions. However, since `itertools` seems to be written in C, this should be faster.

Comment: I didn't know `itertools` were written in C. If that's the case, it is safe to assume that this method is cheaper memory-wise as well.

Comment: @diegoperini Eh, Python has such massive memory overhead involved all over the place (so... many... hashtables...) that it's really not worth thinking about. I also doubt it - objects implemented in C still need to have everything Python objects do, you just shortcut the interpreter for looking up dunder methods.

Comment: @diegoperini I believe that the major speedup of using things "implemented in C" is the fact that the low-level data structure representing python objects has separate fields for special methods, in this case notably `__iter__` and `__next__`, which point straight to the C functions implementing them. This means you don't need to access them "the hard way". (It's also why you can't monkeypatch those methods - for regular Python objects those fields I think are initialised when the object or the type is created, and won't be reassigned when you change them on the Python side later.)

Answer (score 4):

Your `process()` is so open to lazy evaluation, I'd consider using generators to achieve the same effect.

```
#To keep the keys ordered
setup = OrderedDict([('A', 2), ('B', 1), ('C', 3)]) 

def process():
    global setup
    while True:
        for key in setup.iterkeys():
            for value in xrange(setup[key]):
                yield key
```

I can't think a more **pythonista** way.

Comment: How does this guarantee that the keys come out in the original order?  Is that even possible?

Comment: @ScottHunter It doesn't, if the OP wants that he should use an `OrderedDictionary`. And it's up to them to clarify that (perhaps in response to your prompt), not necessarily up to people answering to worry about.

Comment: Added optional line, just in case.

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools

SETUP = {'A': 2, 'B': 1, 'C': 3}

def _build_cycle(setup):
    once = itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(k, setup[k]) for k in setup)
    return itertools.cycle(once)

def _iterator_to_rotating_function(it):
    return lambda : next(it)

process = _iterator_to_rotating_function(_build_cycle(SETUP))
```

As your data source is a dictionary, the order is not defined.

Comment: Where does the return occur?

Comment: +1 for the lambda closure in case the OP really wants a no-param function to yield values. (Even though an iterator `yield`ing them is more idiomatic.)

Comment: Edited slightly to address comments.  @diegoperini, `_build_cycle` returns an iterator that does basically what your answer does.  `_iterator_to_rotating_function` takes an iterator and returns a function that evaluates its next item (I could also do `process = _build_cycle(SETUP).__next__`).

Answer (score 1):

You would need a global variable or an index to pass in in order to keep track. Here is what I have come up with, note that I added a variable index to the global scope.

```
index= -1
def process():
   setupList = []
   for key in setup:
       for val in range(setup[key]):
           setupList.append(key)
   setupList.sort()
   global index
   index += 1
   return setupList[index%len(setupList)]
```